Safari scrolling deactivates first tap on links on an Ipad
I have an app that relies on a webradio and the client wants the radio to keep running as the user navigates the website.
For this We opted for Nextjs and using  the Link component to navigate internally in the app.  we use bootstrap for styling and use the bootstrap javascript for interative elements like modals and tooltips ...
The probleme i have is   on an Ipad after scrolling requires   a double tap to be activated despite seeing the effect of the focus change on the first tap
Originally the component contained a button for custom animations that had no onClick event.
I have tried:
adding a router push to the page i want to navigate to the onclick event
removing the button  and only relying on the bootstrap .btn.btn-primary classes to make it look like a button
i placed Link and anchor outside of all context provider to test  the theory
with javascript active the elements i added act the same as my links in the page
if i deactivate javascript the links work as expected (the layout reloads though... )
